# Accessing PAT,NAT of coverages using arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, vba, esri-coverage-format

I want to access the polygon attribute table (PAT) and node attribute table (NAT) of an arcgis coverage using arcobjects VBA, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to do this [many years ago](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=83002#225206), but haven't tried it lately. [IFeatureWorkspaceFactory.OpenTable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenTable_Method/00250000032v000000/) used to work on tables that would otherwise be hidden (like TIC files).  You need to include the extension as part of their name when opening them though.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the ArcInfo coverage files (pat, nat, aat) to Txt or dbf using these free tools, then query the txt or dbf files from VBA. This solution doesn't require ArcObjects so may or may not be helpful to you. Doesn't run on win7 64bit.

http://code.google.com/p/infolib/

BTW, Ogr2ogr will convert coverage features poly and line (no NAT) to csv,dbf,etc.